# Accessing _this

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tslint

I have a typescript file... and it's failing TSLint.  Was hoping someone could answer this.

So the object looks something like this:

```
export default class Container extends Vue {
    // methods
    doSomething() {
        console.log('something happened')
    }
    items: object[] = [
        {
            title: test,
            onclick: _this.doSomething();
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using `this` instead of `_this`, but `this` only refers to the individual object in items.  So then I found in Chrome dev tools that I can use `_this` to access the containing class.  However, when I put this code thru TSLint, it complains that it **cannot find the name '_this'**.

My project uses `tslint-config-airbnb`.

Thanks.
John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try using `this` and `bind`? So something like

```
items: object[] = [
    {
        title: test,
        onclick: this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }
]
```

Basically we are telling the onclick handler to not change the context of this to the individual objects, but to keep it as the container context.

Comment: Hi, not sure that would work. I tried using an arrow function also, which is supposed to be the same as the bind method. And that didn't work.

Comment: Wow... it worked... but with a small variation.

    items: object[] = [
        {
            title: test,
            onclick: function() { 
                this.doSomething() 
            }.bind(this);
        }
    ]